# How to display 'Iframe content' instead of the placeholder in CKEditor's full package

Tags: ckeditor

For the standard package the Iframes are displayed correctly but that's not the case with the full package. Technically it's possible but I don't know how to do this exactly.

So in the full package instead of a red 'IFRAME' image (placeholder) I want to display its actual content.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to remove the iframe placeholder image, you probably just need to disable the "iframe" plugin.

So in your config.js, add

```
config.removePlugins = 'iframe';
```

Comment: Well, I would like to display the iframe content with some kind of overlay so the user can still change the iframe url/width/height. It might sound silly but it would be kinda useful.

Comment: Then you might consider building a custom widget for iframes: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1 You might be even be able to still use the iframe dialog without the placeholder.